# How to "do something" for each input text files

Tags: awk, gawk

Say that I read in the following information stored in three diffrent text  files (Can be many more)

File 1

```
1 2 rt 45
2 3 er 44
```

File 2

```
rf r 4 5
3 er 4 t
er t yu 4
```

File 3

```
er tyu 3er 3r
der 4r 5e
edr rty tyu 4r
edr 5t yt5 45
```

When I read in this information I want it to print this information from these two files into separate arrays as for now they are printed out in the same time

Now I Have this script printing out all information at the same time

```
{
    TESTd[NR-1] = $2; g++
}   
END {           
   for (i = 0 ; i <= g-1; i ++ ) {
        print "            [\"" TESTd[i] "\"]"

     }
     print "            _____"
}
```

But is there a way to read in multiple files and do this for every text file?
Like instead of getting this output when doing  **awk -f test.awk 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt**

```
    ["2"]
    ["3"]
    ["r"]
    ["er"]
    ["t"]
    ["tyu"]
    ["4r"]
    ["rty"]
    ["5t"]
    _____
```

I get this output

```
    ["2"]
    ["3"]
    _____
    ["r"]
    ["er"]
    ["t"]
    _____
    ["tyu"]
    ["4r"]
    ["rty"]
    ["5t"]
    _____
```

And reading in each file at the time is preferably not an option here since I will have like 30 text files.

**EDIT_*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

I want to do this in awk if possible because I'm going to do something like this

```
{
    PRINTONCE[NR-1] = $2; g++
    PRINTONEATTIME[NR-1] = $3
}
END { 
            #Do this for all arguments once
        for (i = 0 ; i <= g-1; i ++ ) {
             print "            [\"" PRINTONCE[i] "\"] \n"
        }
        print "            _____"
            #Do this for loop for every .txt file that is read in as an argument
              #for(j=0;j<args.length;j++){
        for (i = 0 ; i <= g-1; i ++ ) {
             print "            [\"" PRINTONEATTIME[i] "\"] \n"
        }
        print "            _____"
}
```

Comment: Something like for(i=0; i<args.length;i++){

Comment: See [Is it possible to have different behavior for first and second input files to awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691080)

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, you have an awk script that works and you want to run that awk script on many files and want their output to have a new line(or *_*) in between so you can distinguish which output is from which file.

Try this bash script :-

```
dir=~/*.txt #all txt files in ~(home) directory
for f in $dir
do
    echo "File is $f"
    awk 'BEGIN{print "Hello"}' $f #your awk code will take $f file as input.
    echo "------------------"; echo;
done
```

Also, if you do not want to do this to all files you  can write the for loop as `for f in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt`.

Comment: Could not quite get it to work, when I do this I get the following error "selnc210:/AWK>chmod +x he.sh selnc210:/AWK./he.sh ./he.sh: Command not found. " And the file he.sh contains exactly what you have written

Comment: That is right and wrong, I have A awk script that works, And I want to only do one part of it on as many files that it takes as argument, the rest is it doing correctly, please look at the edit for an example, I only want to do one for loop o all files =)

Comment: @johannes The script is working on my system, did you try changing the directory path to your required directory? And, exactly what error is coming? I run my scripts with `bash`. And i don't understand your edit which has a fictitious code. I saw the sample output that you provided and the output that you want. May be, you can break your awk script in two parts one that you want to do with all files, and one that is working ok.

Comment: How do I change the directory path? It just says  Command not found. ". And what shall I write when calling a bash script, I currently do chmod +x he.sh followed by ./he.sh

Comment: @johannes : If your current shell is not bash then it will tun the script in that shell. Try `bash he.sh` , also if the only error that is coming is command not found then you are probably missing the `./`, else it is not possible. In the first line there is a variable dir, change its value to your working directory, but i don't think that that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it in awk directly. You can call it like this in bash or zsh for example:

```
for fic in test*.txt; awk -f test.awk $fic
```

Comment: Should I print this at the command line, or put this in a separate file, I'm not quite with you, could you please give a little more extended answer that would make my day. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to do it directly in awk:

```
# define a function to print out the array
function dump(array, n) {
    for (i = 0 ; i <= n-1; i ++ ) {
        print "            [\"" array[i] "\"]"
    }
    print "            _____"
}

# dump and reset when starting a new file
FNR==1 && NR!=1 {
    dump(TESTd, g)
    delete TESTd
    g = 0
}
# add data to the array
{
    TESTd[FNR-1] = $2; g++
}
# dump at the end
END {
    dump(TESTd, g)
}
```

N.B. using `delete TESTd` is a non-standard gawk feature, but the question is tagged as gawk so I assumed it's OK to use it.

Alternatively you could use one or more of `ARGIND`, `ARGV`, `ARGC` or `FILENAME` to distinguish the different files.

Or as suggested by see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10691259/981959, with gawk 4 you can use an `ENDFILE` group instead of `END` in your original:

```
{
    TESTd[FNR-1] = $2; g++
}
ENDFILE {
    for (i = 0 ; i <= g-1; i ++ ) {
        print "            [\"" TESTd[i] "\"]"
    }
    print "            _____"
    delete TESTd
    g = 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Write a bash shell script or a basic shell script. Try to put below into test.sh. Then call /bin/sh test.sh or /bin/bash test.sh, see which one will work

```
for f in *.txt
do
  echo "File is $f"
  awk -F '\t' 'blah blah' $f >> output.txt
done
```

Or write a bash shell script to call your awk script

```
for f in *.txt
do
  echo "File is $f"
  /bin/sh yourscript.sh
done
```